# What is our stance on questions on how to operate music production software and not directly on sound design?

Tags: discussion, topic-scope

What is our stance on questions on how to operate music production software and not directly on sound design? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

[Example](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/44468/6753):

> Subject: Is it possible to use the mouse scroll wheel to adjust parameters in Serum in FL Studio?
>
> Body: Is it possible to use the mouse scroll wheel to adjust parameters in Serum in FL Studio? I unsuccessfully tried with FL Studio 12 and FL Studio 20, even though using the mouse scroll wheel does adjust parameters for other (non-Serum) windows in FL Studio.

The tag [fl-studio](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fl-studio) contains many questions of that type.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a reason they wouldn't fit.  Music production software is a tool in the tool belt of sound design and how to use that software seems solidly on topic to me.